# WKWebView not playing audio

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I am setting a WKWebView but, here the web code contains an audio code which is not working in WKWebView. The device I am using is iPad Mini of iOS version 12.3.1

here is the backend code:-

```
<audio id="alertSound" preload="auto">
  <source src="sound/music-box.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  <source src="sound/music-box.wav" type="audio/x-wav" />
</audio>
```

And this is my implementation iOS side

```
    func initWebView() {

    let preference = WKPreferences()
    preference.javaScriptEnabled = true

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.preferences = preference
    configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    configuration.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true
    configuration.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true
    configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []


    self.wkWebView = WKWebView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height), configuration: configuration)
    self.wkWebView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    self.wkWebView.allowsLinkPreview = true
    self.wkWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false
    self.webContentView.addSubview(self.wkWebView)
}
```

The expected result is need auto playing audio when the user is being called in the application using WKWebView

Comment: Did you found out any solution for it because i am also facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your iOS code is right, only need to add **"autoplay=true"** attribute in audio tag, then audio will start automatically play. Please see the below code.

```
 <audio autoplay="true">
        <source src="music-box.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
 </audio>
```

Comment: are you able to autoplay audio file by using the above code?

Comment: actually, this will play the audio as soon as the page is loaded, the audio plays at a specific  point which controlled by conditionals

Comment: I answered as per your question. Your original question was that you want to autoplay audio in the web view. Please edit your question in which point or condition you want to play that audio file.

Comment: Hello @kuldeep I have edited the question now take a look and It would if you can help me with this

Comment: @HarshSrivastava, can you please elaborate on the condition. Do you want to play audio through native code depending on the condition?

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not change, iOS need user click if need play audio. Cant auto play audio.

Answer (score -1):

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *webConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
webConfig.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
    webConfig.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = NO;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Comment: The OP's code already contains this configuration.